# Why is VSZ so huge for the Gnome goa-daemon?

Tags: gnome, services, memory-usage

Trying to track down memory usage on my Ubuntu Bionic Beaver system. Why does `ps` report such a huge VSZ for Gnome's `goa-daemon`?

```
$ ps -eo pid,vsz,sz,rss,comm --sort -vsz| head
  PID    VSZ    SZ   RSS COMMAND
27128 101434964 25358741 3680 goa-daemon
13024 3535356 883839 418848 firefox
 1869 3355792 838948 1204 gnome-shell
13707 2819028 704757 406028 Web Content
13384 2603416 650854 425768 Web Content
```

Have read the man page, I don't even have a `~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf`. So I'm probably not using it.

Why is it reporting a VSZ of 100Gb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed the same on a Linux Mint box: 96G VIRT allocated to `goa-daemon` instances. A search finally revealed [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438572/160424) over on UnixSE:

> All of these daemons use WebKit (mostly to show oauth2 login prompts), and WebKit recently introduced gigacages to isolate the heap used by their JS implementation. The allocation for a gigacage is big enough that any access to an arbitrary unsigned 32 bit offset would still land in the gigacage, resulting in these huge allocations. See this blog post for more details on gigacages: https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/blog/some-brief-notes-on-webkit-heap-hardening/

Comment: Looks like gigacages hurt someones feelings... If I'm wrong, add another answer